# Punctuation before "even" at the end of items in a series

Tags: punctuation, lists

What form of punctuation should precede *even* when it replaces *and* in a series?

> People brought a strange variety of foods to the potluck. The dishes included green bean cookies, grasshopper tacos, durian pudding **( , ) ( — ) ( ; )** even emu casserole.

(Sorry if the example sentence is a bit lackluster; I made it up on the fly.)

Which punctuation is suitable before *even*: a comma, an "em" dash, a semicolon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comma is the most natural in the context of a series.

However, if one wants more contrast/emphasis, the em-dash is better.

The semi-colon doesn't work well here.